# What is the diffrence between types Observable<ObservedValueOf<Type>> vs Observable<Type> in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In typescript @ an angular 2+ project - the IDE gives me warnings that the return type of a function can be either the type **`Observable<ObservedValueOf<Type>>`** or the type **`Observable<Type>`**
I searched the rxjs docs for the [ObservedValueOf](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/type-alias/ObservedValueOf) but there is not much info about that.

Can you please tell me is the difference between the two types?

Comment: The link you posted defines it as `type ObservedValueOf<O> = O;` so no there's no difference at all. It seems to exist purely for enhancing readability / creating self-documenting code so that you can make it more clear what a given type represents.

Comment: I noticed that on this page for the ObservedValueOf is also written: ObservedValueOf  - TYPE-ALIAS. I think you are very right and I now get the idea. So the two types seems to be equal and actually the same thing! Thank you @p.s.w.g !

Answer (score 0):

Actually that link hasn't been updated it seems. If you check the [sourcecode](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.2/src/internal/types.ts#L100-L101), this is what it shows `export type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T : never;`.

So if you check its usage [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/41888efcd1f34de2ee1eda0bd778d4fe0ab4263e/src/internal/observable/combineLatest.ts#L227), its mostly used to assert a type for your input values(source observables) also for resultSelectors.